# how to constrain the uniqueness of two columns while ignoring their ordering in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

In my Postgres database, I use two columns as primary key, for example

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, c)
);
```

I would like to make sure `(c, a)` cannot be added. In other words, if (1, 2) is already in the data base, then (2, 1) cannot be added. Is it possible to add a constrain like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add return based **unique index**, EG:

```
create unique index so45 on example ((ARRAY[greatest(a,c),least(a,c)]));
```

**example:**

```
t=# insert into example select 1,2,3;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into example select 1,2,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into example select 3,2,1;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "so45"
DETAIL:  Key ((ARRAY[GREATEST(a, c), LEAST(a, c)]))=({3,1}) already exists.
```

**In this case you don't need PK to restrict uniqueness:**

```
t=# alter table example drop CONSTRAINT example_pkey ;
ALTER TABLE
t=# insert into example select 1,3,3;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "so45"
DETAIL:  Key ((ARRAY[GREATEST(a, c), LEAST(a, c)]))=({3,1}) already exists.
```

Comment: the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) module allows this solution to be generalized to integer sets of arbitrary length, `create extension intarray; create unique index set_ac on example (sort(array[a, c]));`